# Sample array along path

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have this binary image:

[image: img]

as numpy array of 0 and 1 values.

I want to sample it on every 10th pixel along the path, like:

[image: img]

I know how to sample orthogonal objects, by slicing the array, but I don't know what to do on irregular shape, and get evenly distributed set of "points".

Comment: You need to parameterize the path first.

Comment: If that's the only way, that will be overkill, as above image is too simplified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OpenCV to find the path by `findContours`. Here is the demo code, `x` & `y` are the coordinates of the pixels on the path.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pylab as pl
img = cv2.imread("img.png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,img = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)
r = cv2.findContours(255-img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
c = r[0][0]
x, y = cc[::10, 0, 0], cc[::10, 0, 1]
pl.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
pl.imshow(img, cmap="gray", interpolation="nearest")
pl.plot(cc[::10, 0, 0], cc[::10, 0, 1], "o")
```

Here is the output:

[image]

I just select one point every 10 points from the path, so the distance between two nearby points are not the same. But you can use some interpolation method to convert the path to a smooth curve, and then find equidistance points.

Comment: Thanks, works beautifully! I was trying myself with ndimage label/find_object functions, then through triangulation, but never got there.